# Does Microsoft Photos UWP app not support colour management?

Tags: windows, windows-10, photos, color-profiles

I have noticed that when viewing a set of JPEGs in Photos UWP app that they appear overly saturated and with extra contrast. I saved the JPEGs from RAW files as 8 bits per channel in the sRGB colour space (with colour space embedded) with either Adobe Camera Raw or Photoshop.

When I look at the saved JPEGs in Adobe Bridge or open them up again in Photoshop they look correct.

Interestingly, when I view the original RAW files in Photoshop and then turn on Soft Proofing with the Soft Proof Setup targeting the `Monitor RGB` profile the image in Photoshop now appears the same as the JPEG does in Photos UWP app. It's stated in the Photoshop documentation that the `Monitor RGB` profile simulates display of the document on the monitor as it would appear without colour management. So this leads me to conclude that Photos UWP app is not colour managing my photos.

Why is Photos UWP app not respecting the colour profiles of my photos? Does Photos UWP app not support colour management?

Interestingly the JPEGs seem to appear to have relatively accurate colours in the Photos UWP app on other devices namely laptop and phone.

The machine I am experiencing the problem on is a colour managed machine, calibrated and profiled with a Spyder Pro 4. I'm wondering if the profile created by the Spyder Pro 4 is not being accepted by the Photos UWP app...

UPDATE:

Viewing the photograph in Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer or setting it as the desktop background the photograph appears overly saturated and with excess contrast just as it does in Microsoft Photos UWP app. However viewing the photograph in Chrome or the legacy Windows Photo Viewer it looks natural and the same as it does in Adobe software. Are Microsoft apps/OS using one Colour Engine, Adobe using a different Colour Engine and Chrome using yet another Colour Engine?

Comment: "Are Microsoft apps/OS using one Colour Engine, Adobe using a different Colour Engine and Chrome using yet another Colour Engine?" - Its very possible.  But if the photograph looks the same in IE11 and Edge then that isn't the case.  IE11 is Win32 likewise Edge is UWP.

Comment: Surely Edge and IE11 could both be using the Windows OS colour engine? No?

Comment: Very unlikely.  You can verify if IE11, is using the same engine, by testing  and attempting to verify if the behavior can be replicated on a Windows 8.1 or Windows 7 Virtual Machine.  Microsoft has free VMs, for every virtualization software package, for every supported version of Windows.